# How can I create an interface which has an attribute of type blob in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, geojson

Currently I wish to create an interface which would be used to create an object that would contain results of a database query. One of the object attributes would hold a blob which would be different foe each database retrieval. So is there a way I can make my field of type blob instead of any? If not what should I do?

Here is my interface but I don't feel like keeping the attribute `geometry` as any is the correct approach.

```
"featureStyleName": string,
    "featureType": string,
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": any,
        "featureId": string
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOoAs6QG7WQbwFgAoZM5GCLAVyggGUwBPAGwgDk4BbCALmQDOYKKADmAbhLkKVMLQgAVJgAc+g4WMmlylGnQH8A2lOnki206ear+AIgBis+ba2XLoiAHsewpvwBCLJ4ARuLIAPThyAA8ALzxJm46TnQAkgAm-EIiIBKJpgC++QC6WkXEQA)?

Comment: TypeScript already has an interface type Blob https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.blob.html